# How to highlight the active tabs in navigation bar

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to highlight the active tabs and shift it when i click another links

```js
$(function() {
  $('.nav ul li').on('click', function() {
    $(this).parent().find('li.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
  });
});
```

```css
.nav {
  background-color: #510A32;
  height: 120px;
  background: cover;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 0;
}

.nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.nav li {
  float: left;
  padding: 30px 40px 70px 0px;
  font-family: Arial;
}

.nav li a {
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.nav ul li:hover a {
  color: gold;
}

li.active a {
  color: gold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="nav">

  <ul>

    <li class="active"><a id="home" href="#">Home</a></li>

    <li><a id="story" href="#">Our Story</a></li>

    <li><a id="Menus" href="#">Menus</a></li>

    <li><a id="OrderOnline" href="#">Order Online</a></li>

    <li><a id="contact" href="#contact">Contact & Reservations</a></li>

  </ul>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply this may be this can fix your problem

```
ul li a.active {
  color:blue;
  background:#ccc;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

html goes here...

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#" class="active">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" >Services</a></li>
</ul>
```

Javascript goes here

```
document.querySelector("a").addEventListener("click", function () {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
});
```

Comment: The link "Home" is active and its not highlighting another links even when i click those .

Comment: Add javascript too if it's working fine please upvote me too, Thanks

Comment: @MohammedAbbas hello you can upvote me my answer is working for you.